# How to stop executing map function on array index 5 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

I have array of 10 elements, I am mapping to extract array data . I want to stop array executing when compile reached to array index 5 . I know it possible with for loop but I need it in map function. Please help me

Comment: `map` can't do that but you can achieve that with `reduce` or `filter`

Comment: @Alireza can you please make a simple array and apply this function

Comment: You mean `reduce` and `filter`?

Comment: Why not just map the whole array till the 5th index with a combination of `slice` and `map`?

Comment: Actually you can stop execution using `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map((x,i) => { if(i>=5) throw 0; console.log(x**2) })` - however throw exception will slow down your code and they are not designed for break loops in normal situations

Comment: @Alireza please try best one , actually I want to solve my problem

Comment: What ever requirement you have to accomplish this for is nonsense

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].slice(5)` or `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].filter((el,i) => i <5)` slice is the one for this job. If you need to transform only the first 5 elements chain `slice` with map.